# Building WPF application from Azure DevOps pipeline adds GIT commit hash to the Product version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using dontnet task to create the WPF selfcontained exe.
Initially I was getting Product version as "1.0.0" but now I am getting the version as "1.0.0+GIT commit ID"

I haven't done any changes in the pipeline recently.

Could anyone help me resolve this problem.

[image]

I have tried to remove VersionPrefix and VersionSuffix from CSproj. Also changed the format of DevOps Build number format to "0.1.$(Rev:r)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure Pipelines will use .net8 to build the project.

The issue is from the .net8 SDK. It will include the commit SHA in the informational version automatically.

I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

To solve this issue, you can add the `<IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>` to your csproj file.

For example:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Or you can downgrade the .net version with the task: [Use .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

For more detailed info, you can refer to this ticket: [Git commit ID included in assembly ProductVersion field when building with sdk 8](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/34568)